# Collect Account ID'S On A Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a set of accounts and i want to collect all their id's in a arry so i can use it in a NOT IN operation in a query. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
    @alreadyonteam =  @team.accounts.collect { || . }
```

My query:

```
  @friends = Account.find(current_account.id).active_friends.where('id not in (?)',@alreadyonteam).search(params[:search])
```

Comment: `@alreadyonteam =  @team.account_ids` and that's it.

Comment: @blelump That's worth adding as an answer with a bit more explanation.

Comment: @tadman, you're right, however Simone already did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pluck`

```
@alreadyonteam =  @team.accounts.pluck(:id)
```

Recent version of Rails also introduce `ids`

```
@alreadyonteam =  @team.accounts.ids
```

Comment: Didn't know about that `ids` method. Is that 4.1?

Comment: @tadman it's a 4.0 feature. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/93076168c4d2209e007a32abc7142cc23782d56a).